# Memory leaking when allocating memory

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, dynamic-arrays

I have a function which creates a 2D array:

```
float** createMatrix(int x, int y){
    float** array= malloc(sizeof(float*) * y);
    for(int i=0; i<y; i++)
        array[i] = malloc(sizeof(float) * x);
    return array;
}
```

Now I can create a 2D array:

```
    float** temp=createMatrix(2,2);
```

I also have a function, for e.g., which transposes my "matrix" (2D array):

```
float** matrixTranspose(float** m, int x, int y){
    float** result=createMatrix(y, x);
    for(int i=0; i<y; i++){
        for(int j=0;j<x; j++) result[j][i]=m[i][j];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now if I do this:

```
temp=matrixTranspose(temp,2,2);
```

what happens with the old memory previously allocated to temp? My transpose function allocates new memory chunk. Obviously I would have to somehow free "old temp" after the Transposition, but how (elegantly)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `free` can mirror your allocation:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < y; i++)
    free(array[i]);
free(array);
```

But if you assign to `temp` the new matrix created by `matrixTranspose`, then you'll lose your pointer to that memory. So keep track of that with another pointer, or assign the result of `matrixTranspose` to another pointer:

```
float **transposedMatrix = matricTranspose(...);
```

If you consider your matrices as mutable, you could also transpose them in place: rather than allocating a new matrix in the `matrixTranspose` function, you move around the numbers in the existing array. You can do this in place with one `float temp`.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds obvious. I just thought I might somehow avoid the need for a temporary pointer. Sounds like you can't. Thanks to all of you but I'm gonna accept your answer since you were first.

Answer (score 2):

Use another variable (pointer), when calling `matrixTranspose`. Then, write a function for `free`-ing memory of a matrix.

Like this:

```
float** newTemp = matrixTranspose(temp,2,2);
freeMatrix( temp );
temp = newTemp;
```

Otherwise, you'll loose the memory, pointed by `temp` and thus you have a memory leak.

`freeMatrix` should be symmetric to the allocating memory:

```
for(int i=0; i<y; i++)
    free( array[i] );
free( array );
```

Comment: What would happen after this if I would assign a new array to "newTemp"? Would "temp" also be changed (I suppose not)?  Also, I would need to free "newTemp" after this or it just sits there doing nothing eating space?

Comment: If you assign new arrey to `newTemp` after `temp =  newTemp;`, this will not affect the array, pointed by `temp`. You'll just have 2 arrays and two pointers, one for each of them. You need to `free` all arrays, you don't need anymore. Otherwise, they will just eat you memory. And once you lose a/all pointer/s to some allocated memory, it cannot be freed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You don't do this. You're gonna need two variables for this.

```
float **tmp2 = matrixTranspose(temp, 2, 2);
```

and write a deallocator function for the matrix:

```
void freeMatrix(float **m, int x) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
      free(m[i]);
    }
    free(m);
}
```

and **only then** you can assign

```
temp = tmp2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int FreeMatrix(char **matrix, int x, int y) {
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<y; i++) {
    free(matrix[i]);
  }
  free(matrix);
}
```

The not-so-elegant part, here, is that you have to keep track of the allocated ranges. There are various ways to handle this, most involve keeping track of them, e.g. by wrapping malloc and free. Google for 'malloc free multidimensional arrays'.